# Creating a new instance of a Javascript object

Tags: javascript, class, instantiation

I created a JavaScript object I would like to instantiate a new object every time the user makes a call to the object. However I am unsure as to the proper way to do this. Below is what I have tried:

**JavaScript Object**

```
var parent = (function (){
    var name = null;
    var data = [];  
    return{
        initialize: function(){         
            alert('Hi i am a Parent');      
        },      
        setName: function (aName){
            this.name = aName;
        },
        getName: function(){
            return this.name;
        },

        sayHello:function(name){
            alert('Hi good morning ' + name);
        }
    };
})();
```

I want to make a new instance of this object and call its functions.

This works `parent.initialize();`

However if I attempt `var father = new parent()` I am getting `parent(`) is not a constructor
and if I attempt `var father = new Object()` i am getting `father.initialize` is not a function.

Comment: There is one `)` too many right after `function`.

Comment: `(function)` is a syntax error. Please post executable code.

Comment: devdar: Is there any reason why you put the code in an IIFE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have (if you remove the `)` after `function`) will result in `parent` referring to an object, not a function. You can fix that by just making it a function:

```
function createParent(){
    var name = null;
    var data = [];  
    return{
        initialize: function(){         
            alert('Hi i am a Parent');      
        },      
        setName: function (aName){
            name = aName;         // <== No `this.` here
        },
        getName: function(){
            return name;          // <== Or here
        },

        sayHello:function(name){
            alert('Hi goof morning ' + name);
        }
    };
}

var parent1 = createParent(); // Create a parent
var parent2 = createParent(); // Create another parent
parent1.initialize();         // Call initialize on parent1
parent2.initialize();         // Call initialize on parent1
```

That (a *factory function*) is one of the common idioms for creating objects in JavaScript.

Note that I also removed a couple of incorrect `this.` in there: Your `name` is a variable, not a property. You could make it a property, of course; here's a version with `name` and `data` both being properties:

```
function createParent(){
    return{
        name: null,
        data: [],
        initialize: function(){         
            alert('Hi i am a Parent');      
        },      
        setName: function (aName){
            this.name = aName;
        },
        getName: function(){
            return this.name;
        },

        sayHello:function(name){
            alert('Hi goof morning ' + name);
        }
    };
}

var parent1 = createParent(); // Create a parent
var parent2 = createParent(); // Create another parent
parent1.initialize();         // Call initialize on parent1
parent2.initialize();         // Call initialize on parent1
```

Another common idiom is a *constructor function*, which has a slightly different form and is always called via `new` rather than directly:

```
function Parent(){
    var name = null;
    var data = [];  
    this.initialize = function(){         
        alert('Hi i am a Parent');      
    };
    this.setName = function (aName){
        name = aName;
    };
    this.getName = function(){
        return name;
    };
    this.sayHello = function(name){
        alert('Hi goof morning ' + name);
    };
}

var parent1 =  new Parent();  // Create a parent
var parent2 =  new Parent();  // Create another parent
parent1.initialize();         // Call initialize on parent1
parent2.initialize();         // Call initialize on parent1
```

With constructor functions (which are traditionally given names starting with capital letters), the `new` operator creates the object for you and then calls the function with `this` referring to that new object.

If you wanted to use a constructor function, you could make `name` and `data` properties *and* get the benefit of reusing the functions rather than building new copies of the functions for every `Parent` instance:

```
function Parent(){
    this.name = null;
    this.data = [];  
}
Parent.prototype.initialize = function(){         
    alert('Hi i am a Parent');      
};
Parent.prototype.setName = function (aName){
    this.name = aName;
};
Parent.prototype.getName = function(){
    return this.name;
};
Parent.prototype.sayHello = function(name){
    alert('Hi goof morning ' + name);
};

var parent1 =  new Parent();  // Create a parent
var parent2 =  new Parent();  // Create another parent
parent1.initialize();         // Call initialize on parent1
parent2.initialize();         // Call initialize on parent1
```

Comment: if i want to call just the initialize function would i do createParent().initialize ?

Comment: @devdar: Why would you want to *just* call `initialize`? It doesn't make any sense to create an object, call a function on it, then immediately release it. It would be better to just have the function be standalone.

Comment: different parts of the object function are called at different times however i need all of it to be encompassed into an object not a function.

Comment: Is it possible you can show me how i can call initialize, setName, getName, and sayHello separately from the Parent object e.g. Parent.initialize(), Parent.setName(), Parent.getName()...

Comment: @devdar: You just call the function on the resulting object: `var parent = createParent(); parent.initialize();` I've added the calls above.

Comment: You might want to move the `initialize` stuff right into the constructor/factory function.

Comment: @Bergi: Yeah, not at all sure what devdar is really trying to do here.